# Facebook App - auto login so can update status (php SDK)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I have built an app that allows users to update their status' externally.  It uses the PHP SDK.

Is it possible to automatically login for registered users once they have initially authorised their facebook account via the app?  I do not want them to have to login for every new session. Id like that once they have been authenticated the first time, they are always connected and not asked to login multiple times. Possibly by storing the access token in a database and this using this to connect somehow. Is this possible? I have noticed other apps that do this, but have no idea how they do this  eg. ping.fm

Below is what I have so far, but this requires the user to select the "login" link when the session expires.

```
//instantiate the Facebook library with the APP ID and APP SECRET
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'appid',
    'secret' => 'secret',
    'cookie' => true
));

//Get the FB UID of the currently logged in user
$user = $facebook->getUser();

//if the user has already allowed the application, you'll be able to get his/her FB UID
if($user) {
    //start the session if needed
    if( session_id() ) {

    } else {
        session_start();
    }

    //do stuff when already logged in

    //get the user's access token
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    //check permissions list
    $permissions_list = $facebook->api(
        '/me/permissions',
        'GET',
        array(
            'access_token' => $access_token
        )
    );

    //check if the permissions we need have been allowed by the user
    //if not then redirect them again to facebook's permissions page
    $permissions_needed = array('publish_stream', 'read_stream', 'offline_access');
    foreach($permissions_needed as $perm) {
        if( !isset($permissions_list['data'][0][$perm]) || $permissions_list['data'][0][$perm] != 1 ) {
            $login_url_params = array(
                'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access',
                'fbconnect' =>  1,
                'display'   =>  "page",
                'next' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
            );
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);
            header("Location: {$login_url}");
            exit();
        }
    }

    //if the user has allowed all the permissions we need,
    //get the information about the pages that he or she managers
    $accounts = $facebook->api(
        '/me',
        'GET',
        array(
            'access_token' => $access_token
        )
    );

    //save the information inside the session
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
    $_SESSION['accounts'] = $accounts['data'];

    $facebookAuth = TRUE;
} else {
    //if not, let's redirect to the ALLOW page so we can get access
    //Create a login URL using the Facebook library's getLoginUrl() method
    $login_url_params = array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access',
        'fbconnect' =>  1,
        'display'   =>  "page",
        'next' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    );
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);

    //redirect to the login URL on facebook
    $facebook_login = $login_url;
}

if (isset($_GET['submit'])){

    if ($_GET['facebook']){

            //get the info from the form
            $parameters = array(
                'message' => $_GET['message']/*,
                'picture' => $_POST['picture'],
                'link' => $_POST['link'],
                'name' => $_POST['name'],
                'caption' => $_POST['caption'],
                'description' => $_POST['description']*/
            );

            //add the access token to it
            $parameters['access_token'] = $_SESSION['active']['access_token'];

            //build and call our Graph API request
            $newpost = $facebook->api(
                '/me/feed',
                'POST',
                $parameters
            );

            if ($newpost){
                echo 'posted to facebook';  
            } else {
                echo 'not posted to facebook :0(  ';    
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not check how ping.fm does it.
But after looking at the extended permissions list here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

xmpp_login (Provides applications that integrate with Facebook Chat the ability to log in users.)

Otherwise, i dont think its possible.

Even desktop Apps need to redirect the user to a browser for authentication.

This also may depend on whether the user has the "keep me logged in" checkbox marked on log-in.

Since you have the offline_access, then you basically can perform the actions regardless if the user is logged in or not.